# Php Simple Html - How to convert the DOM to an Element

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm using  `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` library in my project, but I can't figure out how to make a method working.

First I convert a string into a DOM object:

```
$html = str_get_html($rarr[$i]);
```

the `$rarr` variable is an array of html string elements. I want to remove their `class` and `title` attributes, so I use the following code:

```
$html = $html->removeAttribute('class');
$html = $html->removeAttribute('title');
```

but I get the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom::removeAttribute() in **/scripts/defios.php** on line **198**

According to [Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm#api), the `str_get_html()` *Creates a DOM object from a string.* and I think the `removeAttribute()` method is not a DOM method but an Element method and that's why I get the error. So I need to convert somehow the DOM to Element. I think the `find()` method would do the job, but the problem is that I can't use it because the html elements in the array are randomly (some are divs, spans and they don't have a common class or id), so the method doesn't really help me. More the DOM itself is the element so I do not want to select something inside the DOM but to convert the entire DOM to an Element.

All I need to do is to remove that class and title, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you not find my answer helpful? Please let me know how I could better improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would remove those:

```
foreach($html->find('[class]') as $el) $el->removeAttribute('class');
foreach($html->find('[title]') as $el) $el->removeAttribute('title');
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to access the *children* attribute: Take a look at the following example and tweak it to work!

```
    $html = str_get_html($rarr[$i]);
    foreach($html as $e)
    {
        $tag = $e->children[0]; // get the outer most element
        $tag->removeAttribute('class');
        $tag->removeAttribute('title');
    }
```